# Copy output of a shell command to a variable and need to make output data's comma separated

Tags: bash, docker, unix, sh, concatenation

I am trying to get the IP's of the docker containers and need to pass the IP's as comma separated.

Using below command i am able to get the container ip's

```
sudo docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $(sudo docker ps -q --filter "name=slave")
```

output-->

```
> 10.17.0.4
> 10.17.0.3
> 10.17.0.2
```

> Need help to save the output IP's to a variable and process IP's to be comma separated like **10.17.0.4,10.17.0.3,10.17.0.2**

Comment: pipe the data to `tr`.  eg, `sudo ... |  tr \\n , | sed 's/,$//'`

Comment: These IP addresses are basically useless in many contexts: you cannot reach them from other hosts, you cannot reach them from the same host on MacOS, and they’ll change whenever you delete and recreate a container.  I’d find a different way to accomplish your higher-level goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an old version of Docker (info). So the below command will not work in the new version of Docker

```
sudo docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $(sudo docker ps -q --filter "name=slave") | sed -n -e 'H;${x;s/\n/,/g;s/^,//;p;}'
```

In the New version of Docker, you can try the below command.

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $(docker ps -q  --filter ancestor=adminer) | sed -n -e 'H;${x;s/\n/,/g;s/^,//;p;}'
```

You can filter base on the image using below command in New version, this will return all the container ID, other wise old commands will return only one container in the new version.

```
docker ps -q  --filter ancestor=image_name
```

[image]